# ec2インスタンスにsshした状態でec2インスタンスにgithub 組織のリポジトリをgit cloneしたいがエラーが出ます。

Tags: github, amazon-ec2

ec2インスタンスにsshした状態でec2インスタンスにgithub 組織のリポジトリをgit cloneしたいがエラーが出ます。

これには私もPAT（パーソナルアクセストークン）が求められるのは存じているのですが、設定したPATをPASSWORD挿入時に入れても403エラーが発生します。

トークンは「Fine-grained personal access tokens」で発行し、組織オーナからPATの承認が下りています。

エラー文

```
Cloning into 'hogehoge1'...
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://pell@github.com': 
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/organization/hogehoge1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

sshキーを発行して承認する方法もダメでした。
何を確認し、どうすれば解消の糸口を見つけられるでしょうか？